# How to open shared files from windows connected pc on LAN

Tags: networking, windows, samba, lan, sharing

I am in college. I want to open the shared files by all the windows laptops connected to LAN in our hostel. How to do that because it was really easy on windows. I am new to ubuntu so please give me complete guide.

Answer (score 1):

There's help for this at the following location:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html

In order to connect to a network share, you would open Nautilus ("Files" on the launcher), and click "Connect to Server" in the left pane. When prompted, enter the samba share protocol followed by the IP address of the computer (or FQDN...):

smb://192.168.1.16 (for example)

Hope this helps.